# House's furnace died while fermenting, what should I do?

Tags: fermentation, fermentation-temperature

I'm doing my first homebrew (using [this kit](http://brooklynbrewshop.com/beer-making-kits/everyday-ipa-1-gal-kit)), and started fermentation 6 days ago. I've kept it in my basement, which is usually around 66F. The kit's instructions just tell me to let it ferment in a dark place for 2 weeks.

Yesterday my furnace went out, and the temperature's dropped to about 55F. Is this going to affect the brew? If it drops to the low 50s for the next couple days, will it ruin the batch?

I could move the carboy to a friend's apartment where it's warmer, but will moving it be worse than letting it get cooler?

Comment: What yeast was included in the kit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd leave it alone. After 6 days at 66F fermentation should be done or nearly done. Even if it isn't, most yeast will continue to metabolize sugars at 55 F. Once the heat comes back on, if the yeast haven't finished their work already, they'll become active again and finish the job.